# How to include npm dependencies when building typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

When doing `tsc` everything compiles to my dist folder. But how can I include npm dependencies into the dist folder also?

This is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude":[
    "./redis",
    "./mongodb"
  ]
}
```

package.json build script is just like this:

`"build": "tsc"`

When i move the dist folder out of the project folder and try to

`node dist/index.js` I am missing dependencies needed.

For example:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'bullmq'
```

I tried to just copy over the whole `node_modules` folder to `dist` but then I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vismasync/node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/encoding.js:2:21)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a typescript-specific problem, but it's how a node application work.
For a node application with dependencies, all the dependencies is stored under `node_modules`. So that's why you need to run `npm i` to deploy a project.

For your problem, sounds like what you need is a bundler which, as its name suggest, bundle everything including your code dependencies into one giant js file. Then you can use this js file without `node_modules`. In this case, check out rollup or webpack.